# Wordpress and Linking Pages to Custom Post Type Pages

Tags: wordpress

I am having trouble coming up with a solution for the following scenario in WordPress. In general, I would like to link to services and locations bi-directionally. Lets take the following example of services and locations to help explain...

**Services are broken into several sections... Each service is a page.**

```
Services Section 1
- Service 1
- Service 2
- Service 3
- Etc…

Services Section 2
- Service 1
- Service 2
- Service 3
- Etc…
```

One service can have multiple locations associated with it.

**Locations are broken down by several regions… Each location is a page (this would be a CPT).**

```
Locations West
- Location 1
- Location 2
- Location 3
- Etc…

Locations East
- Location 1
- Location 2
- Location 3
- Etc…
```

One location can have multiple services associated with it.

**Now for the use cases/functionality...**

*User Case 1*

If I browse to Services Section 1 and then Service 2. I would see a page with general information about that service and a section calling out all the locations that have this service available that is broken down by region. I could then click one of the locations and it will take me directly to that location page to get the address/phone/etc....

*Use Case 2*

Lets say I browse to Locations East and Location 3. I would get a page with the location info, address, phone, link for directions, but also a call out to all services offered at that location. If I select a service, I would then be taken to that service page.

I thought I could do this with taxonomies, but it appears taxonomies group things but would not link directly to that service or location page, instead it seems it will display a list of all pages tagged with that service/location. Which is not a use case that I would like.

Hoping to get ideas/thoughts on how to best accomplish this. Any replies/help would be very much appreciated. Hopefully the above explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could a) use MicroKids Related Posts, which would let you associate the pages/posts with each other and then you can modify your theme to display those results somewhere.

Otherwise, I think you can still use taxonomies - but you'd want to associate the Pages/Posts together with a taxonomy somehow - for example, maybe a taxonomy for Services that you associate to each Location. Then on the Services page, you would write a WordPress loop (or use a plugin to generate and output one) that displays the links to each Location that is in the specific Service (taxonomy) that you need to show.